# I'd like to use the iPad virtual keyboard like a peripheral for a desktop computer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, keyboard, peripherals

I'd like to use the iPad virtual keyboard like a peripheral for a desktop computer, just as a substitute of the original keyboard, any ideas? I didn't find anything on the net. A good solution for me is a 40 PIN apple adapter to USB or PS2 connector, best if this adapter is wireless.

Comment: Why not just use one of the many apps available that do this for you via wireless?  This is not really an SO question though.

Comment: I need to create an app over it. The pc is a Cachier POS with no access.

Comment: Because POS Cashier PCs doesn't support bluetooth..... of course